# Закрытие элемента по клику на кнопку

Tags: jquery

Доброго времени суток, вообщем сложилась такая ситуация, есть 3 кнопки по нажатию на кнопку, открывается определенное поле формы, нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку предыдущее поле которое было открыто скрывалось. Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно поступить в такой ситуации.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".viber-btn").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.phone-number-viber').show();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.phone-number-viber').hide();
        }
    });
    $(".whatsup-btn").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.phone-number-whatsup').show();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.phone-number-whatsup').hide();
        }
    });
    $(".skype-btn").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.login-skype').show();
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $('.login-skype').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".viber-btn").click(function(){
    $(".active").not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.phone-number-viber').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за помошь, очень помогло